# Iserializable to serialize readonly methods to be sent through webservice

Tags: c#

I am sending an object through a webservice with readonly methods.
I am using the Iserializable interface, assuming that I would no longer need a parameterless constructor. This is not true and I still cannot send my object over the wire.

```
public class Foo:  ISerializable
{
 public boolean IsBusy { get; private set;}
 protected Foo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
  {
this.IsBusy = info.GetBoolean("IsBusy");
 }
   void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   {
 .AddValue("IsBusy", this.IsBusy);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what a read-only method is.  But ISerializable only works for binary serialization.  A web service uses XML serialization, a parameter-less constructor is required.

One trick you could use is to attribute it so that client code can never use it directly:

```
 [Obsolete("For serialization only", true)]
 public Foo() {}
```

Comment: I should've said  read-only property. Sorry for the confusion
I am referring to *

public boolean IsBusy {get; private set;}*

a property with a public getter and private setter.

Comment: XML serialization doesn't allow that either.  Use a "proxy" class if necessary, a simple helper that merely copies the properties that need to be serialized.